# Adding both Google Analytics code and Google Ads conversion tracking code to the same page

Tags: google-analytics, javascript

I am managing a very simple single page site, and my client wants to start a Google Ads campaign for it. I had added some days ago the Google Analytics tracking code to the page:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX');
</script>
//G-XXXXXXXXX is my Analytics code
```

(I am not using Google Tag Manager because it's a quite simple site, I know how to edit HTML by hand, and we're not planning on using any more tags).

Now, today I started setting up the Ads campaign, and it recommended that I add an Ads conversion tracking code for the event we're after (page views). The code it showed me was this:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Ads: YYYYYYYYY -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-YYYYYYYYY"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-YYYYYYYY');
</script>
// YYYYYYYY is my Ads account code, I suppose
```

Don't they look pretty much the same, except for the ID numbers? So which code should I add and in what order? Both, neither, one or the other?

---

EDIT: did the above, but now I have a slight problem (which I don't even know if it's really a problem), which is that the "Website traffic" default event created in Ads appears as non-verified, and doesn't register conversions. See screen cap:

[image: Screencap]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge the two. Just add the config line of the Google Ads tag after the config line of the GA tag.

This is one of the benefits of the gtag system. You can track multiple accounts with the one tag.

Comment: Just a question: is this valid for Google Analytics 4 too? I'm asking because I set it up as advised days ago, and yet I have no conversions listed, so I don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes. Just add its config line to the existing tag. A basic tag will not track conversions, you have to add a purchase event or set up other events as conversions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And what if my conversion event is just a page view? (I just want people to see my website). Do I leave the code just as is?

Comment: How have you implemented the conversion?

Comment: I hadn't (oops...). I didn't realise at first about the changes in GA4, so I just added the code quoted above: the JS code and then the two gtag config lines, without doing anything else.  After I realised something was wrong, I went into GA4 and enabled "first_view" as a conversion event... and now I am registering conversions there, so it seems like it's working. The only strange thing to me now is that the "Website traffic" default event still shows up as "Unverified" and with 0 conversions, when I'm most definitely getting traffic.

Comment: Is the Website traffic conversion based on GA4?

This sounds more like you are creating audiences, not conversions?

Comment: I don't know, to be quite honest. I didn't create the "Website traffic" event, it was already there when I entered the "Conversions" page. Also, I haven't created any audiences; it's a quite specific product, and those who search for it will fall naturally in a given demographic (without us needing to target it).

Comment: Are you looking at GA4 conversions when you talk about the Website traffic event, or the conversions in Google Ads? A screenshot of this conversion may help.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I meant the conversions in Google Ads. I've edited the question to add the screenshot where you can see the different conversions that appear.

Comment: That looks like a website conversion that requires a special tag on the pages that will trigger that conversion. The name "Website traffic" is confusing. What actual conversion do you want to track with it? Just visiting the website is not a good conversion. If it worked, it would mean everyone converts.

Comment: I hear you, but in this case it's a very simple website with no ecommerce, little more than an online brochure, and we were just trying to get the brand known in the local region where it operates. As mentioned, after a few days I added "first visit" as the main conversion event we are targeting, which I feel is the most adequate for us, and that one is firing correctly.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath: I am a little confused about this answer. I understand that we can add the config line of Google Ads to Google Analytics, but what about the very first line? I have explained my question [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/141627/how-to-combine-google-analytics-and-google-ads-tags-into-one-script)