# How to combine Google Analytics and Google Ads tags into one script?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, google-tag-manager

I want to add Google Analytics and Google Ads tags to my website:

This is for Google Analytics:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxxxxx-x"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
   gtag('js', new Date());
   gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-x', { cookie_domain: 'my-domain.com', cookie_flags: 'SameSite=None; Secure' });
</script>
```

This is for Google Ads:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-yyyyyyyyy"></script>
<script>
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
   gtag('js', new Date());
   gtag('config', 'AW-yyyyyyyyy');
</script>
```

How should I combine them in one script to be added to my site:

Should I do this:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxxxxx-x"></script>
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-yyyyyyyyy"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
   gtag('js', new Date());
   gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-x', { cookie_domain: 'my-domain.com', cookie_flags: 'SameSite=None; Secure' });
   gtag('config', 'AW-yyyyyyyyy');
</script>
```

or should I do this:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxxxxx-x"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
   gtag('js', new Date());
   gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-x', { cookie_domain: 'my-domain.com', cookie_flags: 'SameSite=None; Secure' });
   gtag('config', 'AW-yyyyyyyyy');
</script>
```

Note: I have seen [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/133594/adding-both-google-analytics-code-and-google-ads-conversion-tracking-code-to-the) question but it does not answer what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

You only need a single call to googletagmanager.com/gtag

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on this?

Comment: Thanks but what id should I use in that call?

Comment: The ID is the primary ID for the gtag. I would use the AW one, as UA is going away soon.

If you follow what happens on the network, it will actually make extra gtag requests for each other ID specified in a config command. So you only need to do one yourself, to get the ball rolling.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486130/how-to-combine-google-analytics-and-google-adwords-gtag-js) answer, here is how we can merge the two tags:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxxxxx-x"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
   gtag('js', new Date());
   gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-x', { cookie_domain: 'my-domain.com', cookie_flags: 'SameSite=None; Secure' });
   gtag('config', 'AW-yyyyyyyyy');
</script>
```

And [here](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7548399?hl=en) is the documentation from Google.